# Getting value from textbox and use function with button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string from textbox, then with a button I want to show longest string from text box and show result (longest word) on another label or in the textbox.

In order to do this I tried the code below:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">


    function LongestWord() { 

        var text = document.getElementsById("txt1").value;
        var str = text.split(" ");
        var longest = 0;
        var word = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (longest < str[i].length) {
            longest = str[i].length;
            word = str[i];
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("txt2").value = word;
};

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
  Type your string:<br>
  <input type="text" name="textBox1" id="txt1" /><br><p>

  <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Find longest word in your string" onclick="LongestWord();" /><p>

  Longest word is;<br>  
  <input type="text" name="textBox2" id="txt2"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click button code is not working even if I put a string to first textbox. Can you please advise me what to do?

Also I will evaluate code like I will take function from .js file.

Comment: What is `clickevent` here?

Comment: I highly recommend reading [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and more specifically the "Spelling, grammar and formatting" section. I've corrected this post, and fixed some of the common mistakes, but on future posts reading this article would go a long way to making high quality posts for future visitors.

Comment: Your code has errors (one extra "};" that shoudn't be there. Review it before asking :)

Comment: The statement `var str = sen.split(" ");` should be `var str = text.split(" ");` , IMHO

Comment: @FrankerZ ,ty for advicing. I read post and i ll try to fix my style like you advised.

Comment: @tomsihap , you know sometimes even if you review you can miss little things, but ty for pointing out! :)

Comment: Please do not include your solution in the question itself: instead, post your solution (replacing `getElementsById` with `getElementById`) in its own answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var firstButton = document.getElementById("btn1");

  your function

firstButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
  your_function_name()
})
```

PS.
In this line

```
document.getElementById("txt2").innerHTML = word
```

Change .innerHTML to .value

Answer (score 0):

Put the code near closing end of the body.Have done few correction in your snippet and have added comments

```js
function LongestWord(string) {

  // Use index when using getElementsByName.
  // trim to remove white space
  var text = document.getElementsByName("textBox1")[0].value.trim();
  //sen is not defined ,replace with text
  var str = text.split(" ");
  // sort the array by the length of the each string
  var grtString = str.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.length - b.length
  })
  // index 0 will first element
  // if two string are of same lenth then it will give first one
  document.getElementById("txt2").value = grtString[0];
};
```

```html
<form>
  Type your string:<br>
  <input type="text" name="textBox1" id="txt1" /><br>
  <p>

    <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Find longest word in your string" onclick="LongestWord();" />
    <p>

      Longest word is;<br>
      <input type="text" name="textBox2" id="txt2"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: This one finds shortest one.

Comment: @Erikin Just swap `return a.length - b.length` with `return b.length - a.length`

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of errors in your code but the number one issue is getElementsByName returns a nodeList, not an element.

I tried to just update yours without rewriting it. Using better variable names will help quite a bit.

```js
document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = LongestWord;

function LongestWord() {

  var text = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
  var str = text.split(" ");
  var longest = 0;
  var word = null;

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (longest <= str[i].length) {
      word = str[i];
    }
  }
  
  document.getElementById("txt2").value = word;
};
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Testing</title>

</head>

<body>

  <form>
    Type your string:<br>
    <input type="text" name="textBox1" id="txt1" /><br>
    <p>

      <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Find longest word in your string" onclick="LongestWord();" />
      <p>

        Longest word is:<br>
        <input type="text" name="textBox2" id="txt2"><br>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: By the way this code works pretty fine with codesnippet in this page. However it is not working on my computer. What should i check? I checked code and it is exactly like @JasonB 's code.

Comment: You can update the question to show your code and get more eyes on it. It may not be exactly the same as the snippet

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use `getElementsByName`, you have to specify index. Because `getElementsByName` returns collections. Since you have `id` in that element it is always better to use `id` with `getElementById`.
2. `input` elements does not have property `innerHTML`. Use `value` instead.

Try the following:

```js
function LongestWord() { 
  var text = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
  var str = text.split(" ");
  var longest = 0;
  var word = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (longest < str[i].length) {
        longest = str[i].length;
        word = str[i];
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("txt2").value = word;
};
```

```html
Type your string:<br>
<input type="text" name="textBox1" id="txt1"/><br><br>

<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Find longest word in your string" onclick="LongestWord()" /><br><br> 

Longest word is;<br>
<input type="text" name="textBox2" id="txt2"><br>
```